# Spark parse XML with multiple types

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I have the following XML and I am using https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-xml to import as dataframe

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <row>
        <property key="id">1</property>
        <property key="fname">x</property>
        <property key="lname">y</property>
        <property key="address">
            <address>
                <street>999 abc WAY</street>
                <zip>9999</zip>
            
            </address>
        </property>
        
    </row>

    <row>
        <property key="id">2</property>
        <property key="fname">a</property>
        <property key="lname">b</property>
    </row>
</root>
```

I use the following logic to import as Spark DataFrame

```
  val testData = spark.read
      .option("rootTag", "root")
      .option("rowTag", "row")
      .XML("./test.xml")
```

But o/p

```
testData.show(false)
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|property                                                                                          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[{null, id, null}, {null, fname, null}, {null, lname, null}, {null, address, {999 abc WAY, 9999}}]|
|[{null, id, null}, {null, fname, null}, {null, lname, null}]                                      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

without address node in XML

```
scala> testData.show(false)
+---------------------------------+
|property                         |
+---------------------------------+
|[{1, id}, {x, fname}, {y, lname}]|
|[{2, id}, {a, fname}, {b, lname}]|
+---------------------------------+
```

How to parse in a situation where a node has multiple types of values. One is text and other is the address object.